# Plot mean/variance over number of simulations

Tags: r, plot

Unfortunately I don't know the name of this kind of plot/calculation method:
There is an outcome from the single'runs' from a MCS. To show converence I want to plot the mean and/or variance of every adding step in R.
E.g.

```
outcome <- c(1,1.2,0.8,0.9)
```

In the graph: mean = 1 over step 1, mean = 1.1 over step 2... What is the standard method? How to perform this growing number of means/variance?
Thanks!

Comment: you mean the cumulative mean?

Comment: step by step, so if you take the outcome, first it's the mean of the first number (1), then of 2 numbers (1 and 1.2), then of (1, 1.2 and 0.8) etc...

Comment: Like the first graph: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518906/plotting-convergence-of-monte-carlo-estimation-of-pi-to-display-convergence-rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. you are looking for cumulative mean:

Here is a ggplot version:

```
outcome <- c(1, 1.2, 0.8, 0.9)
cumulative_mean <- cummean(outcome)

# Create a data frame with the cumulative means and their indices
df <- data.frame(cumulative_mean = cumulative_mean, index = 1:length(cumulative_mean))

# Plot the cumulative means
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = cumulative_mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Index") +
  ylab("Cumulative Mean") +
  ggtitle("Cumulative Mean Plot")+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

And here is base R version:

```
plot(cumulative_mean, type = "p", xlab = "Step", ylab = "Cumulative Mean")
```

[image]

Comment: thank, this is the mean of one number now: but there should be at index 1: (1/1=1), index 2: ((1+1.2)/2 = 1.1), index 3: ((1+1.2+0.8)/3 = 1) etc.